# Date Calender Count

Tags: java, calendar, salesforce

Could you help me with the problem below. 
I got the error `"No access to entity: Calendar in row 1, column 8"`, but I didn't know exactly the error.

Is the following syntax ok?

```
IF(Calendar.Year(EZR.Beginn_der_HV__c) = This.Year) { 
  Bestandsentwicklung_CY++; 
}
```

The field `Beginn_der_HV__c` includes dates. I want to count the `Beginn_der_HV__c` if the calendar year from this field is like current year, also I need to count the field if the calendar year from this field is like current year - 2.

Thanks for your help,
peX

```
public class testfor6_c {

private Id accId {get; set;}
public testfor6_c(ApexPages.StandardController stdcontroller) { 
    accId = stdcontroller.getRecord().Id;

    Bestandsentwicklung_CY = 0;
    Bestandsentwicklung_CY_2 = 0;

    getEZRen();   
}

public Integer Bestandsentwicklung_CY {get; set;}
public Integer Bestandsentwicklung_CY_2 {get; set;}

public void getEZRen() {

List<Einzelrisiko__c> EZRList = [SELECT Beginn_der_HV__c FROM Einzelrisiko__c WHERE Abgangsdatum__c = Null AND Unternehmens_Id_Long__c = :accId]; 

FOR (Einzelrisiko__c EZR : EZRList) { 

    IF(Calendar.Year(EZR.Beginn_der_HV__c) = This.Year) { Bestandsentwicklung_CY++; }
    IF(Calendar.Year(EZR.Beginn_der_HV__c) = This.Year-2) { Bestandsentwicklung_CY_2++; }    

} } }
```

EDIT 24.10.2014

Hi,

I tried some other syntax for the calendar problem, but I still get errors.

**ERROR: variable does not exist: Year**

```
IF(EZR.Beginn_der_HV__c.year() = This.Year) { Bestandsentwicklung_CY++; }
```

**Expression cannot be assigned**

```
IF(EZR.Beginn_der_HV__c.year() = Date.today().year()) { Bestandsentwicklung_CY++; }
```

Please help me.

Thanks, peX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is so easy - **double =** is necessary

```
IF(EZR.Beginn_der_HV__c.year() == Date.today().year()) { Bestandsentwicklung_CY++; }
```